# How do I handle oom when executing sql with cnosdb?

Tags: cnosdb

When I executed the sql, I found that the cnosdb process suddenly disappeared, there was no error message in the cnosdb log, and then I found an error message in the system log, the following is my information, how should I deal with this situation? Are there any configuration items that can solve this problem?

Machine information:

```
OS: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPU: 16 core
Memory: 32G
```

CnosDB version:`cnosdb 2.3.0, revision c3e7e09`

Data size:`14G`

Starting mode:`nohup ./target/release/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_8902.toml -M singleton &`

SQL:

```
SELECT "WatchID", "ClientIP", COUNT(*) AS c, SUM("IsRefresh"), AVG("ResolutionWidth") FROM hits GROUP BY "WatchID", "ClientIP" ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 10;
```

System error information:

```
Jun 7 19:48:04 test-gitlab kernel: sled-io-5 invoked oom-killer:gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jun 7 19:48:05 test-gitlab kernel: oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jun 7 19:48:09 test-gitlab kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice,task=cnosdb,pid=16407,uid=0
```